# MongoParseError: No username provided in authority section

Tags: mongodb, npm, nodemon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeoUE.png)

Having issues trying to "nodemon --exec npm start" it just comes up with this every time, I've tried everything I possibly could to fix it and still no luck, if someone could find a solution I would love you forever.

Comment: Could you share your `package.json` and the code you use to establish your Mongo connection?

Answer (score 0):

Look like your connecting string is wrong.

Check whether your mongodb connecting string is available or not.

Comment: I have this as my current string "mongodb://jack:Backtohome11@localhost/casino" and I'm able to connect to the database through Navicat and Robo 3T. But for some reason it still says that "MongoParseError: No username provided in authority section" stuff

Comment: I've been having issues with this for like the past 8 hours, I've looked everywhere for a fix and have been out of luck. I'm able to connect to the db with navicat and robo 3t so the username, password, and database name is correct

Comment: Create another basic and clean project to test the mongodb connecting string.

Comment: Sorry, im just not able to do that right now, its getting quite late and im running out of time, I was looking for a quick fix/solution on here since i spent hours and hours looking everywhere else.

Comment: missing port? `mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/mydb`

Comment: just added :27017 and its still saying same thing